# How can you split a string in bash script by starting at a certain char and ending at another

Tags: linux, bash

i have an email address and i am wanting to split the email in the first letter of the firstname and full last name and put them in a place holder.
eg:
firstname.lastname@email.com

```
x = f 
y = lastname
```

I did use try `firstCharacter=${email:0:1}` to get the first char but am not sure how to get the last name.

Full code here

```
#!/bin/bash

file="users.csv.1"
Count=0

while IFS=";"; read email birthDate group sharedFolder
do
        echo -e "Email: $email"
        firstCharacter=${email:0:1}
        echo $firstCharacter
        IFS="."
        read -ra
        echo -e "Birth Date: $birthDate"
        echo -e "Group: $group"
        echo -e "shared Folder: $sharedFolder\n"

done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
local_part=${email%%@*}     # remove trailing `@*` (glob-style pattern)
last_name=${local_part##*.} # remove the leading `*.` from above
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea using parameter expansion/substitution:

```
$ email='firstname.lastname@email.com'
$ lastName="${email//@*}"                   # strip off domain (ie, everything from @ to end of string)
$ lastName="${lastName//*.}"                # strip off everything from start of string up to to and including last period; should address email addresses like 'firstname.mi.lastname'
$ typeset -p lastName
declare -- lastName="lastname"
```

Comment: Can you explain the last two lines please.

Comment: `typeset -p` displays the variable name (`lastName` in this case), some attributes (`--` in this case) and the value stored in the variable (`lastname` in this case); `typeset` is a synonym for `declare` (ie, `declare -p lastName` would display the same thing)